# How to write to Database from datahandler?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datahandler

I have a datahandler for my Sencha Touch application and am trying to write to a database.  When reading from a database, I call `reader.Read()` and that works just fine.  What should I call to run an `insert into` query on my database from the datahandler?  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ExecuteNonQuery (or async equivalents) of the SqlCommand class.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was able to successfully write to the database.  Appreciate your time.